# How do I authenticate user in REST web service?

Tags: rest, methods, restful-authentication

How do I write the method for user authentication in REST web service?
I am beginner with web services.

Comment: There are different ways to authenticate user in REST web services. You have to give more information to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i authenticate for user in REST web service in web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529221/how-do-i-authenticate-for-user-in-rest-web-service-in-web-application)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Authentication itself should be done in a stateless way, so that the REST paradigm is not broken. This means authentication has to occur on every request.
this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454355/security-of-rest-authentication-schemes) might provide some further details

the esiest method is using HTTP-Basic AUTH ([rfc2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)) over SSL encrypted connections (https). here are some java examples:

- [ericonjava](http://www.ericonjava.com/?p=325)
- [my blog entry](http://objecthunter.congrace.de/tinybo/blog/articles/89)

another method is using nonces so that you dont have to resend the user/pass combo everytime, but they are a bit more challenging:

- [Nonce Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050932/nonce-usage-in-authentication)

there are lots and lots of ways to authenticate users but these 2 are the most often used that dont hold session state on the server side.

hope that helped